# How to change SharePoint 2013 Masterpage?

Tags: sharepoint-enterprise, custom-masterpage, branding

I have a requirement to change the layout of the SharePoint search page to match the look and feel. I tried adding the CSS file, but that didnt help.

I figured I would have to change the masterpage to get the exact look and feel.
The site consists of boostrap and other stuff, I am having a hard time figuring out how to go ahead with it

1. should I put everything(the HTML, CSS and bootstrap file) into a wsp solution and upload it and try to apply it.
2. Should I just upload the master page as the wsp solution?
3. Is there any other way in which I can go about and do this.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Its an Enterprise Search Center instead of a Basic Search Center then you should be able to change the master page to a custom master page in Site Settings.  The Enterprise Search Center uses publishing which surfaces a link to change the site and system master page.  The Basic Search Center doesn't use publishing so to change the master page there you would need to either build a feature, use **SharePoint Designer** or use **PowerShell**.

**Here's how to change the master page in a publishing site:**

[Creating customized search results in SharePoint 2013](http://www.abelsolutions.com/totm/creating-customized-search-results-in-sharepoint-2013/)

[Customizing Search in SharePoint 2013 using Display Templates](http://www.justanothertechnologyguy.com/2013/09/customizing-search-in-sharepoint-2013.html)

[Basic Search Center – SharePoint 2013 and Office 365](http://support.bind.pt/hc/en-us/articles/204447769-Basic-Search-Center-SharePoint-2013-and-Office-365)

**UPDATED**

You need to copy the original master page & start applying CSS on it. It would be really easy to get the desired output with that copied master page.

Comment: Have you tried above solution? Is it working for you?

Comment: Ive got a new issue now. The umbraco desigfn is an MVC3 razor design, so it doesnt have a master file, it just has a template HTML file and JS and CSS with it.  I'm having a hard time figuring out how to get the search site to look exactly like the template.  @Hardik

Comment: I do not know anything about umbraco design. So I think its hard for me to help you but as you required the change the layout of the SharePoint search page. I gave you the above solution. Thanks.:)

Comment: I appreciate your help @Hardik , but the above solutions are kind of modifying the search result layout, i wanted to do the branding for the page.

Comment: Added one more link in my answer. Please check it. Hope it helps you.

Comment: Kindly let me know if that link won't work for you.

Comment: Have you tried the last link from my answer?

Comment: have you tried the last link from my answer?

Comment: I have designers that supplied me with a HTML file, a template that want to see on the search site. The search site which is a Enterprise search centre in SharePoint 2013 needs to look like the template.  Since this is a HTML file, I tried uploading it in the master page, but it says snippets are missing. So, I am trying to figure a way for it.

Comment: BTW you need to copy the original master page & start applying CSS on it. It would be really easy.

Comment: I will kiss you if you break it down for me.

Comment: What are you saying? as i told you to work on copied search masterpage & apply it to your search site. I had already done that way to achieve my desired design. It is working fine.

Comment: Did you got it working for you?

Comment: when I convert the Html into master page i get errors and warning which redirects me to a page which says that the snippets are missing??

Comment: Obviously it did the same thing as master page contains the **contentplaceholders** which are not available in your **HTML** pages. that's why i suggest you to copy the original one & use the copy master page & change it as per your need.

Comment: BTW you took long time to achieve this. you can get idea from above links as well as check videos available on YouTube.

Comment: My given answer didn't helped you?

Comment: Thank you for your help and concern my friend, I really appreciate it. I did modified the original masterpage and then published and enabled it, the I called a CSS file from site settings as well, so that helped it and finally I completed my work.

Comment: It's nice to hear from you that you finally completed it. Kindly do some justice to my answer. Glad to help you.

Comment: would you write the copy master page and edit it as an answer to the question so that I can upvote it, you mentioned that in the comments.

Comment: Did that. If it's fine for you than kindly accept it if it helps you. Thanks.

Comment: I gave access as visitors to people, they cant see the CSS.. the users that have access as the members can see the CSS

Comment: You need to put the file into your master page solution than after it will work for other uses as well... If it's not a solution than just put it in style library & give reference from there in master page